# What's wrong with maximum-scale=1.0?

Tags: iphone, css, responsive-design

I've heard a few grumblings from the web community about people using `maximum-scale=1.0` within `meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;` because it prevents people zooming in.

The reason I use it is that as soon as the mobile device is turned landscape things seem to readjust, affecting the layout.

My first question is: is maximum scale really so bad?

and secondly, what is the alternative to prevent the iPhone or smartphone automatically adjusting the content when I don't want it to?

Thanks

Comment: My only real comment is that often people with poor eyesight will need to zoom your page to be able to read the text. Also, people have gotten used to pinch-to-zoom behaviours so when it doesn't work it can be quite disconcerting. Just my opinion, and you have a cool character portrait :-)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense about why people don't like it. I just don't really see the alternative. The iPhone messes up my design when things rotate :-(

Answer (score 1):

I don't like ppl who calls good features wrong or bad. They think `maximum-scale=1.0` is bad because it disables an accessibility issue. People who has sight problems will want to zoom in and when you disable it, it's bad for them, i agree. But depending on your project, it may be very fair to disable that feature.

`initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;` is the only way i know (except completely disabling rotation feature from the system globally) so i have no answers for the second question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, unfortunately I will have to continue to set a maximum scale until someone comes up with an alternative. Seems a bit broken to me.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference, I've even tried applying it to all elements with the global selector *